# Symfony3 form: View transformer error suggests using view transfomer

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I wanted to create a simple `HiddenEntityType`, so that I can have hidden form fields that represent an entity. The simplest solution by far looked to be to employ a (view) transformer.

However I cannot see to get it to work.

Based on documentation [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html)
[image]

...the forward `transform` needs to return something you can put into HTML, a string(e.g. the id of my entity) and the `reverseTransform` must transform an id into an entity.

With that in mind here is the simple class I made:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;


use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\CallbackTransformer;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class HiddenEntityType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $entityManager;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $repository = $this->entityManager->getRepository($builder->getDataClass());
        $builder->addViewTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
            function ($entity) use($repository) { //Forward
                dump('Forward');
                dump($entity);
                if (!is_null($entity)) return $entity->getId();
                return $entity;
            },
            function ($id) use($repository) { //Reverse
                dump('Reverse');
                dump($id);
                return $repository->find($id);
            }
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'hidden';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => null,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I receive the following illogical error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class AppBundle\Entity\MyEntity, but is a(n) integer. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms a(n) integer to an instance of AppBundle\Entity\MyEntity.").

When creating the form, based on the dumps you see above, the forward transform is called twice - once with `null` and once with the `AppBundle\Entity\MyEntity` as its argument.

What might I be doing wrong?

`Sy 3.3.6`
`PHP 7.1.8`

Comment: What value do you set to this form element type? Integer (id) or entity?

Comment: An entity. Did try it with id too, in which case the forward transform is, predictably, called with an integer.